# Noob Here - What is used in this picture?

Tags: graphic-styles

I am a noob in graphic design at all, so I am sorry if this question is idiotic.
But can anyone tell me how can I edit my photos like this?

I mean how can add background like this? What is used here? Adobe Photoshop or something else? Thanks in advance!

(This pic is from Instagram post of a movie production house.)

[image]

Comment: Nearly any image editing software works.

Comment: Photoshop works well. It's a multilayer composition, not very complex one. If you have Photoshop or GIMP, check this https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsfhmiv4xxjd1tv/stclause.psd?dl=0 It's another composition, not the same, but has quite the same complexity. Close the layers one by one to understand how  it's built.

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create that effect with a photo of yours too, using Photoshop or GIMP.

On Photoshop, open your image where you want to cut your face/body out. Using various tools available on Photoshop, select the required area and delete the rest in the layer. [Click here for a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hw0-SehGcgg)

Create a new layer and add the background color to it and place it behind your actual photo in the layer panel.

Double press your photo layer to add "Stroke" to give the red outline. [Click here for a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iy-9P99fNCc)

Add the required text using the Text Tool.

You can download various Icons in PNG format and import them into your composition as required.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Welcome! You can choose to select the answer as the correct one if it works for you!